# Copy part of dictionary (both its keys and its value)

Tags: python, dictionary

In my case, I need to transfer part of a dictionary to a persistent storage:

```
adict={'a':'aaa','b':'bbb','c':'ccc'}
newdict={'a':'aaa','b':'bbb'}
```

I tried to use dict.fromkeys(['a','b']), this only give me default None Values, unless I specific the value for these keys. What I hope is there is some function automatically default values to the ones the original dict already has. Something like

```
newdict=adict.fromkeysautomatic(['a','b'])
```

I know it is easy to write a function to so do so, but I believe there should be some built-in mechanism already, since this should be some frequent behavior. But didn't get it by searching myself.

Comment: It's not a good idea to do `dict = ...` because `dict` is already a function.

Comment: i don't think there is a built-in dictionary methods to do that, you ve to choose either dict comprehension or calling some kind of function to map the values.

Answer (score 34):

Using dict comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'a':'aaa','b':'bbb','c':'ccc'}
>>> newdict = {key:d[key] for key in ['a', 'b']}
>>> newdict
{'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb'}
```

Side note: Don't use `dict` as a variable name. It shadows builtin [`dict` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding the **dict comprehension** which is only available in newer version of Python (*2.7+*) you can also do:

```
d = {'a':'aaa','b':'bbb','c':'ccc'}
dd = dict((k, d[k]) for k in ("a", "b"))
```