# How to serialize only some fields in json in python?

Tags: python

I've already read a lot of different sites, but I can't find information on how to exclude some fields from json serialization in python. I would like to serialize only the necessary pair of fields

I have a check_method field in the Host class. Here it is set using self and when I use json.dumps for serialization, it gets into the output file.

If I remove self, then the field becomes inaccessible from the main code.

The described class is part of a class AppConfig. AppConfig is a class containing the usual fields. The get_hosts() method returns an array of hosts.

AppConfig class that is serialized using json.dumps()

```
import json

class Host(object) :
    otval_date = ''
    otval_cnt = 0
    
    def __init__(self, name : str, host : str, check_method : str, http_code : str, stop_after : bool, notify : bool):
        self.name = name
        self.host = host
        self.check_method = check_method
        self.http_code = http_code
        self.stop_after = stop_after
        self.notify = notify

class AppConfig(object) :    
    def __init__(self, config : any):
        self.log_important = config['log_important']
        self.await_time = config['await_time']
        self.ips = get_hosts(config['ips'], 'ping')
        self.domains = get_hosts(config['domains'], 'curl')

def get_hosts(conf_host_objs, check_method) -> list :
    hosts_list = []
    for host in conf_host_objs:     
        hosts_list.append(Host(
            name         = host['name'],
            host         = host['host'],
            check_method = check_method,
            http_code    = host['http_normal_code'] if 'http_normal_code' in host else '',
            stop_after   = host['stop_after'] == 1,
            notify       = host['notify']
        ))
    return hosts_list

# test example
config = {'log_important': False, 'await_time': 2, 'ips': [{'host': '192.168.0.1', 'name': 'local network', 'stop_after': 1, 'notify': False}, {'host': '8.8.8.8', 'name': 'google dns', 'stop_after': 1, 'notify': False}], 'domains': [{'host': 'stackoverflow.com', 'name': 'stackoverflow.com', 'http_normal_code': 200, 'stop_after': 0, 'notify': True}]}

APP_CONFIG = AppConfig(config)

# Here the main work happens with the APP_CONFIG class. 
# It can change, expand, contract, and so on

json_config_dumps = json.dumps(APP_CONFIG, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)

print(json_config_dumps)
```

What do I need to do to continue seeing the field in the main code? But at the same time, so that it is initialized when creating a class in the constructor. The field can be static. I don't change it from the main code.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the relevant JSON call(s). What do you use `json.dump()` on? A class like this by itself, is not JSON serializable.

Comment: @9769953, oh, I'm sorry. I made a typo. The original call is json.dumps() 

`json_config_dumps = json.dumps(APP_CONFIG, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)`

I use `__dict__` because it is not one class and there is a different level of nesting

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that call, since it may be (very) relevant. Also: what is APP_CONFIG? And I don't see a Host object there.

Comment: APP_CONFIG is a class containing the usual fields. The get_hosts() method returns an array of hosts. Edited in more detail in the question. And added the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy part of dictionary (both its keys and its value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084066/copy-part-of-dictionary-both-its-keys-and-its-value)

Comment: @tevemadar I don't understand how I can exclude some class fields from serialization using json.dumps() or other ways to perform serialization in json. I know that in other languages, as a rule, it is possible to set the necessary annotations for fields so that they are used only in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to serialize only some fields in json in python?

You simple pass to the json serializer only the fields you're interested in serialising and nothing more.

How to do that? simple make either a function or a class method that return a new dictionary, list or whatever json compatible thing you're interested in it with the thing you want.

for example, said you only want to serialize only certain parts of the following class A and B, then you can do as follow

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, a: str, b:str):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def to_json(self) -> dict: # add a method to make it json compatible
        return {"A":self.a}

class B:

    def __init__(self, a: str, b:str):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

def b_to_json(inst_b: B) -> list: # add a function to make it json compatible
    return [inst_b.b]
```

and use them accordingly

```
>>> import json
>>> a= A("hello", "world")
>>> b= B("buu","this is b")
>>> json.dumps(a.to_json())
'{"A": "hello"}'
>>> json.dumps(b_to_json(b))
'["this is b"]'
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x000002C56D6366D0>
>>> b
<__main__.B object at 0x000002C5700584D0>
>>>
```

to get the thing back from the json, then you need the make the inverse function (in the example above that isn't really possible because one of the attributes is missing in the json result, so a default value is needed to fill the gab so you aren't guaranty to get a exact copy of the original)

> What do I need to do to continue seeing the field in the main code? But at the same time, so that it is initialized when creating a class in the constructor. The field can be static. I don't change it from the main code.

I'm not sure what you mean by that, serializing an object doesn't destroy or remove the original object, it just make a new one in a new form